# {{base_url}} is not recommended to use in a production environment to declare the Base Unsecure URL / Base Secure URL

Tags: configuration, base-url, system-config

`{{base_url}}` is not recommended to use in a production environment to declare the Base Unsecure URL / Base Secure URL. It is highly recommended to change this value in your Magento configuration.

I got this error in Magento admin.

what does it mean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Go to `System->Configuration->web`
2. open `unsecure,secure` Tabs
3. Put your site's URL in those tabs.

See the image below.

[image]

Comment: And if you are like me and broke your site because you put in a bad base_url value inadvertently, here is guidance how to get out of trouble - https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/39752/how-do-i-fix-my-base-urls-so-i-can-access-my-magento-site