# How do I fix my Base URLs so I can access my Magento site?

Tags: database, magento-1, migration, base-url

- I changed Base Urls and now my website is inaccessible
- I moved everything to a new server, didn't change the base_url and my website is inaccessible

How do I change or restore base_url my BaseURL settings?

Answer (score 78, accepted):

**Symptom:** I changed Base Urls and now my website is inaccessible or I moved everything to a new server, didn't change the `base_url` and my website is inaccessible.

### How to change or restore base_url settings with phpMyAdmin

Instructions are for a simple "one store" website where the "default store view" is set to inherit its setup from the "default config". There will be an additional instance of the below mentioned table rows for each unchecked `Use Website` checkbox.

1. Open your `core_config_data` table in phpMyAdmin.
2. Sort table by `path` column and find the following rows for your **unsecure section**, they should look like the following:

Columns

```
PATH                         VALUE
web/unsecure/base_url        http://www.example.com/
web/unsecure/base_link_url   {{unsecure_base_url}}
web/unsecure/base_skin_url   {{unsecure_base_url}}skin/
web/unsecure/base_media_url  {{unsecure_base_url}}media/
web/unsecure/base_js_url     {{unsecure_base_url}}js/
```

3. Replace `http://www.example.com/` with your appropriate domain url (trailing slash necessary) and if you’ve installed in a subfolder append it with a `/` after it.
4. Find the following rows for your **secure section**, they should look like the following:

Columns

```
PATH                        VALUE
web/secure/base_url         https://www.example.com/
web/secure/base_link_url    {{secure_base_url}}
web/secure/base_skin_url    {{secure_base_url}}skin/
web/secure/base_media_url   {{secure_base_url}}media/
web/secure/base_js_url      {{secure_base_url}}js/
```

5. Replace `https://www.example.com/` with your appropriate domain url (trailing slash necessary) and if you've installed in a subfolder append it with a `/` after it. If you haven't received your security certificate and enabled TLS/SSL yet, use `http` instead of `https`
6. Clear contents from `var/cache`, `var/session` directories after changing `base_urls`.

Clearing cache and sessions is necessary because your config is cached and clearing it forces a reread of the configuration data from the `core_config_data` table and reestablishment of sessions with the proper information.

**NOTE:** If you have set your `base_url` correctly for `web/unsecure/base_url` and `web/secure/base_url` you do not have to mess around with changing the `{{UNSECURE_BASE_URL}}` and `{{SECURE_BASE_URL}}` macros in the rest of the entries.

### How to change base_url settings with mysql from the command line

1. Log into your MySQL database, replace $USER with your database user name and $DBASE with your database name. It will prompt you for your password:

`mysql -u $USER -p $DBASE`

2. Below are the SQL commands to change your base_url values. Replace unsecure `http://www.example.com/` and secure `https://www.example.com/` (if you have SSL/TLS enabled, else https should be http) with your appropriate domain url (trailing slash necessary) and if you’ve installed in a subfolder append it with a `/` after it.

SQL Commands

```
UPDATE core_config_data SET value = 'http://www.example.com/' WHERE path LIKE 'web/unsecure/base_url';
UPDATE core_config_data SET value = 'https://www.example.com/' WHERE path LIKE 'web/secure/base_url';
```

3. Check your base_url settings with the following:

SQL Commands

```
SELECT path,value FROM core_config_data WHERE path LIKE 'web/unsecure/base%';
SELECT path,value FROM core_config_data WHERE path LIKE 'web/secure/base%';
```

4. Clear contents from `var/cache`, `var/session` directories after changing `base_urls`. Clearing cache and sessions is necessary because your config is cached and clearing it forces a reread of the configuration data from the `core_config_data` table and reestablishment of sessions with the proper information.

Comment: Note: In extreme cases where your permissions on the `var/` directory are messed up, Magento will store the Magento cache in the system `/tmp` directory [as documented here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8940458/cant-change-magento-base-url-stuck-in-cache/8947825#8947825) and clearing the cache doesn't clear the cached config entries pulled from `core_config_data` until server reboot or someone with sufficient rights can delete Magento's mislaid cache.

Comment: For finding that misplaced cache directory, if you can install `n98-magerun`, use the command `n98-magerun.phar sys:info` to get a basic system info listing with one item being `Cache Directory` location.

Comment: this works for me perfectly.

Comment: I had to add the step of running the following Magento command to this: `php bin/magento cache:flush`. I will add that if you have a multisite setup as we do, you will want to be specific with the config_id you target and make sure to update for all sites.

Comment: I wasn't able to login anymore and I discovered that I had to update also the value for the path `web/cookie/cookie_domain`

Answer (score 23):

In Magento2, there is also a way to do this directly via Magento using below commands rather than having to go through SQL which i find a bit quicker.

Within Magento’s root directory run below commands:

1. Set **Unsecure URL**

   ```
   bin/magento setup:store-config:set --base-url="http://www.magento2.com/"
   ```
2. Set **Secure URL**

   ```
   bin/magento setup:store-config:set --base-url-secure="https://www.magento2.com/"
   ```
3. **Clear Cache**

   ```
   bin/magento cache:flush
   ```

Comment: You might also need edit base_link_url after this.

Comment: for anyone that has redirected all traffic through https setting the base URL as https will solve this problem (eg. when installing SSL certificate with Certbot)