# I can't login to Magento after changing the base url. Website is gone!

Tags: error, cache, backend, base-url

[How do I fix my Base URLs so I can access my Magento site?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/39752/how-do-i-fix-my-base-urls-so-i-can-access-my-magento-site)

I found a similar question that was already answered. I followed the steps but I still can't recover the website or get into Magento backend. 
I followed the steps and changed the secure and unsecure base url back to their original value. I cleared every var/cache and var/session folders as well. I still see this when trying to access the backend site:

Not Found

The requested URL /index.php/admin was not found on this server.

Help would be VERY much appreciated.

Comment: Do you have `redis` or similar caching system installed?

Comment: No, I do not have anything like that installed.

Comment: I hope you have added `/` at the end of each url and can you give me your url if it is live. And also try without "index.php" (example.com/admin)

Comment: I did indeed add the trailing slash at the end of each url. 

www.cablings.com

I also tried without "index.php" with no luck.

Comment: From looking at your url I can guess you haven't correctly set those data for each fields (base url, skin, media etc) and also set these to `0`: `web/secure/use_in_frontend` and `web/secure/use_in_adminhtml`

Comment: I haven't changed any of the values for skin, media, link. The base url value is set to: "http://www.cablings.com/shop/". Also "web/secure/use_in_frontend" and "web/secure/use_in_adminhtml" are both set to 0.

Comment: check system.log file there is any error shows?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but if you have done everything it is your `.htaccess` problem.

Since you have installed magento in sub folder.

Go to `.htaccess` file and replace following:

```
#RewriteBase /magento/
```

to

```
RewriteBase /shop/
```

We have commented out the `RewriteBase` first and changed `magento` to `shop`.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Once I figure out how to do that I'll let you know if it works. Most likely it will be tomorrow since it is currently past 9pm. Thank you for all your assistance.