# Admin Panel Error After change in Use Secure URLs

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, configuration

> I change  `Use Secure URLs` in Admin Configuration `No` from `Yes` then  my full admin panel has been changed.

[image]

[image]

Comment: have you tried to check where is your css gone?? see browser console log

Comment: i see my browser console log but it's ok...!

Comment: impossible, it will show you exact error.

Comment: open your console log then reload a page and post your screenshot here...so only the people understand the problem in the adminpanel

Comment: CSS is not loading on the frontend in Magento ver. 1.9.1.0

Answer (score 0):

See if your problem is getting fixed by clearing the Cache (System -> Cache Management). You may need to do this manually by emptying the contents of var/cache.

If you are using CDN like Cloudflare, make sure all files are purged.

Comment: submit button not work

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that the URL's are correct and you have SSL correctly set up then clearing your cache should fix this issue, as suggested by Renish K.R.

Since you can't clear the cache from Admin you will have to do this manually by deleting the contents of var/cache in the Magento root directory.

If you don't have SSL correctly set up, you will need to manually revert your change by editing the relevant values in core_config_data which is covered here: [How do I fix my Base URLs so I can access my Magento site?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/39752/how-do-i-fix-my-base-urls-so-i-can-access-my-magento-site)

Answer (score 0):

You can revert your changes by going into the db, table `core_config_data` and remoging the rows with `path` column `web/secure/use_in_adminhtml` and `web/secure/use_in_frontend`.

clear the cache when you are done.